# XML Restful parsing

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax, jquery

I need to search for a 'term' and then display the data in the html page.
See more info here.
http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/webservices.html
The data that needs to be displayed is

```
"title"
"FullSummary"
"groupName"
"snippet"
```

I am a beginner when it comes to ajax and javascrpt

What I have so far is:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function DoSearch() {
'http://wsearch.nlm.nih.gov/ws/query?db=healthTopics&term='($get("searchterm"), DoCallback);
}
function DoCallback(result) {
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
$get("searchterm").innerHTML += results[i] + "<br/>";
}
}
</script>

</head>


<body>

<form name="input">
      Search Term: <input type="text" name="searchterm" value=""><br>
      <input type="button" onclick="mySearch()" value="Search">
</form>

<div id="searchResultsPlaceholder">resultsDiv
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone advise?

Comment: What is RESTful parsing?

Comment: Not going to happen, it is a cross domain call. [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: espascarello, how will I search this web service then?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax will work based on Same Origin Policy.
Assume you are using Same Origin Policy while accessing url via XMLHttpRequest

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mySearch()
{
var term =  $("#searchterm").val();
 $.get("http://wsearch.nlm.nih.gov/ws/query",
 {
 db:"healthTopics",
 term:term
 },
 function(result,status){
 var resultHTML=""
 for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
 resultHTML + =  results[i] + "<br/>";
}
$get("searchResultsPlaceholder").innerHTML =resultHTML;
  });
}
</script>

</head>


<body>

<form name="input">
      Search Term: <input type="text" name="searchterm" value=""><br>
      <input type="button" onclick="mySearch()" value="Search">
</form>

<div id="searchResultsPlaceholder"></div>

</body>
</html>
```